# Node js : process.stdin.on and testing a number with typeof vs isNaN

Tags: node.js, nan, typeof

I'm learning web development and starting my journey with node.js (already worked on JS), so sorry if my question is noob's one :) I've already found some similar questions in the forum but not exactly the same, and still don't understand what is happening.

I don't know why **typeof** does not seem to work in node.js, as it is working with JS in the console. I managed to make it work with **isNaN** function, but can someone explain me what is happening with typeof function ?

```
process.stdin.resume()
process.stdin.setEncoding('utf8')

console.log('What\'s your age ? ')
process.stdin.on('data', (int) => {
    if (int > 99 ) {
        console.log('Enter an age below 99')
    } else if (typeof int != 'number') {
        console.log('Enter a number')
        console.log(int)
        console.log(typeof int)
    } else {
        let year = 2020 - int
        if (year > 2020) {
            console.log("Year is above 2020")
        } else {
            console.log('Hello you were born in ' + year)
        }
    }
    process.exit()
})
```

Trying with an age of 39, it logs 'Enter a number', even if it is a numeric entry... ! Console.log (typeof int) gives me 'string'.

If I change the code with isNan function, it works perfectly :

```
process.stdin.resume()
process.stdin.setEncoding('utf8')

console.log('What\'s your age ? ')
process.stdin.on('data', (int) => {
    if (int > 99 ) {
        console.log('Enter an age below 99')
    } else if (isNaN(int)) {
        console.log('Enter a number')
        console.log(int)
        console.log(typeof int)
    } else {
        let year = 2020 - int
        if (year > 2020) {
            console.log("Year is above 2020")
        } else {
            console.log('Hello you were born in ' + year)
        }
    }
    process.exit()
})
```

Does it have something to do with process.stdin.on statement ?
Thanks a lot for your answers !

Comment: I would suggest doing `parseInt(int, 10)` with try/catch so that you can be sure you're dealing with a number. I would expect the data event to be giving you a string and I hate the implicit type conversions of JS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`typeof` doesn't work because the callback to `process.stdin.on("data", callback)` will receive a String after you call `readable.setEncoding("utf8")`.

See [node.js docs](https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_readable_setencoding_encoding):

> By default, no encoding is assigned and stream data will be returned
>   as Buffer objects. Setting an encoding causes the stream data to be
>   returned as strings of the specified encoding rather than as Buffer
>   objects. For instance, calling readable.setEncoding('utf8') will cause
>   the output data to be interpreted as UTF-8 data, and passed as
>   strings. Calling readable.setEncoding('hex') will cause the data to be
>   encoded in hexadecimal string format.

Additionally, `typeof aStringValue === "number"` is `false`.

```js
const foo = "foo";
console.log(typeof foo === "number"); // false
```

`isNaN` will cause the String to be converted to a number which is why your second example works.

---

In any case, I think the easiest way to deal with all this is to use `parseInt(int, 10)` with a try/catch to explicitly convert the data to a number instead of using so many implicit casts.